# Load data to Azure Blob from python data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload data from python dataframe into Azure Blob.

I have been using this to download data from Azure Blob which works:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
from io import StringIO
blob_service_client = 
BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["blob_conn_string"])
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(blob_container,file_name)
Localfile = blob_client.download_blob().content_as_text()
        
df_data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(Localfile))
```

I want to load the df_data back to Azure blob container.
I tried the following code:

```
blob_client.upload_blob(df_data)
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can save an in-memory pandas dataframe in Azure. Try to convert it to a parquet/csv/txt file and give it a retry

Comment: @flow_me_over I was able to get it done after converting it to csv

Comment: @flow_me_over We can't directly save pandas dataframe in Azure. We need to convert it to csv/txt in memory then we can upload it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I did to resolve this:

```
def blob_conn(df,blob_name):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["blob_conn_str"])
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=os.environ["container"],blob=blob_name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(df, overwrite = True)
```

I am passing the 'df' as a csv file using the data frame and blob_name as the location.

Answer (score 1):

As flow_me_over says in the comment, `blob_client.upload_blob(df_data)` is impossible.

The type allowed in `upload_blob()` should be `Union[Iterable[AnyStr], IO[AnyStr]]`, but the type of `df_data` is `TextFileReader`.

Below code can work with no problem:

`blob_client2.upload_blob(Localfile)`

Or

`blob_client2.upload_blob(data=df_data.to_csv(index=False))`

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to @flow_me_over  above -  I was able to get it done converting it to csv